# SQL calculating percentage

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, percentage

I am trying to get a claim denied percentage count (total_count / denied_count * 100) for providers with under 100 claims.  I am able to get the total count and denied count with separate queries, but I am having trouble pulling everything together.

```
SELECT
    PROVID,
    COUNT(CLAIMID) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
    COUNT(CLAIMID) / (SELECT COUNT(CLAIMID) * 100 
                      FROM #TEMPSTAGE 
                      WHERE STATUS = 'DENY') AS DENIED_PERCENTAGE
FROM 
    #TEMPSTAGE
WHERE 
    PROVID IN (SELECT DISTINCT PROVID
               FROM #TEMPSTAGE
               GROUP BY PROVID
               HAVING COUNT(CLAIMID) <= 100)
GROUP BY 
    PROVID
```

Results example:

```
ProvID / Total_Count / Denied Percentage
-----------------------------------------    
X12345  / 77       /     0
```

I am getting zero denied percentage for everything as my subquery in the select statement isn't allowing me to group by provid.

Error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

What's the best way to go about this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per most languages, if you do `1 / 2` with integers, the result is `0`, because there is no integer for `0.5`.  To get a decimal (fixed point of floating point) you need to convert the datatypes.

How depends on your dialect of SQL *(MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc)*.

```
CAST(COUNT(CLAIMID) AS FLOAT)

CAST(COUNT(CLAIMID) AS DECIMAL(10, 4))

COUNT(CLAIMID) * 1.0

etc, etc
```

Next, to use `IN` the list needs to be in braces `IN (1, 2, 3)`, but to use a sub query the query needs to be in braces `(SELECT x FROM y)`.

That means to use both you need two pairs of braces `IN ((SELECT x FROM y))`

So, the smallest changes to your query are...

```
SELECT
    PROVID,
    COUNT(CLAIMID) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
    COUNT(CLAIMID) / (SELECT COUNT(CLAIMID) * 100.0
                      FROM #TEMPSTAGE
                      WHERESTATUS = 'DENY') AS DENIED_PERCENTAGE
FROM 
    #TEMPSTAGE
WHERE 
    PROVID IN ((SELECT PROVID
               FROM #TEMPSTAGE
               GROUP BY PROVID
               HAVING COUNT(CLAIMID) <= 100))
GROUP BY 
    PROVID
```

That said, the subquery in where clause can just be moved to the main query...

```
SELECT
    PROVID,
    COUNT(CLAIMID) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
    COUNT(CLAIMID) / (SELECT COUNT(CLAIMID) * 100.0
                      FROM #TEMPSTAGE 
                      WHERE STATUS = 'DENY') AS DENIED_PERCENTAGE
FROM 
    #TEMPSTAGE
GROUP BY 
    PROVID
HAVING
    COUNT(CLAIMID) <= 100
```

Also, I've removed the `DISTINCT` keywords.  If you're using `GROUP BY` the way you are you don't need it.

***EDITTED*** : Following comment

You can skip the sub-query and just sum the number of rows in the group where the status is `'DENY'`.

Also, a percentage is `(x * 100) / y` not `x / (y * 100)`, so I reversed the calculation.

```
SELECT
    PROVID,
    COUNT(CLAIMID) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'DENY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(CLAIMID) AS DENIED_PERCENTAGE
FROM 
    #TEMPSTAGE
GROUP BY 
    PROVID
HAVING
    COUNT(CLAIMID) <= 100
```

Comment: You are amazing.  Thank you so much!  This was bothering me.